# Understanding type of object in Python

Tags: python, c++, object

I've always programmed in C++ and now I'm learning Python. 
I find very confusing the absence of declaration of objects in Python, especially the fact that members of classes are not declared before being defined.

For example in C++ I would write:

```
Class ComplexNumber {
    protected:
    int _re,_im;

    public:
    ...

}
```

In Python the declaration of _re and _im would be missing and their initialization would be hidden in the definition of public members. When you are lucky you find them in the constructor, but sometimes they are initialized in other members.

Is there any method to figure out the complete structure of classes in Python without reading the whole code? In particular I'm interested in the full list of the "variables" (and their types) contained in the classes, which in C++ are usually protected/private members.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you want `dir(some_object)` but it's unclear to me what you're asking

Comment: With type hinting and the `inspect` module, you can make Python look more like C++. But the point of learning a new language IMO isn't to try and replicate what you already know, but rather to learn the pros and cons of doing something a new way e.g. Python's duck typing.

Comment: the full list of the "variables" (and their types) NO, no types in python, unless you mean at runtime, you can get the attributes you would have at runtime like @roganjosh suggested. but not before hand

Comment: You can use an IDE PyCharm is my choice it will help you show what is available without running the code.

Comment: That's the beauty of Python, creating dynamic objects on the fly. You can think of the variables in Python as a `var` (in c#) or `auto` in c++ 2010+. There's no need for hard typing because we trust the coder to use their variables correctly. If for some reason you wanted to check a typing in your code, you can use `type()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is a dynamic language. Variables don't have types, variables hold references to objects. Only objects have types. So before runtime, there is no way to know what type a variable holds. Python developers should work around this with good clear documentation explaining what the expected type is.

At runtime, we can see what the type of each attribute (aka member) of a python object (the instance, not the class) is:

```
def types_of_instance_attributes(instance):
    return {k: type(v) for k, v in vars(instance).items()}
```

---

However, in python 3.6+ static type *hints* have become part of the language to help users document and allow static type checkers to work better. These look more similar to C++:

```
class ComplexNumber:

    _re: int
    _im: int

    def __init__(self, real: int, imaginary: int) -> None:
         self._re = real
         self._im = imaginary

    def magnitude(self) -> float:
       return (self._re**2 + self._im**2)**0.5


com = ComplexNumber(12, -3)

x = com._re  # type checker knows is an int
y = com.magnitude()  # type checker knows is a float
z: str = com._im  # ERROR in type checker (int -> str mismatch)
```

Comment: Thank you, vars() is exactly what I was looking for.
In addition I have found that using PyCharm you can visualize the structure of the classes with Ctrl+F12.